# how to click on h1 header to navigate to component?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I am trying to change the  header to a link that calls for Homepage component. Right now it displays a logo title.  But I want my users to be able to click on it to direct them to the landing page .

```
import React from 'react';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import AuthContext from '../../context/auth-context';
import './MainNavigation.css';
// import Homepage from '../../pages/Homepage';

const mainNavigation = props => (
  <AuthContext.Consumer>
    {context => {
      
      return (
        <header className="main-navigation">
          <div className="main-navigation__logo">
            <h1>Lux Lab Hair Salon</h1> // ....... change this to a link
          </div>
          <nav className="main-navigation__items">
            <ul>
              <li>
                <NavLink to="/events">Available Hours</NavLink>
              </li>
              {!context.token && (
                <li>
                  <NavLink to="/auth">Sing In | Sing Up</NavLink>
                </li>
              )}
              
              {context.token && (
                <React.Fragment>
                  <li>
                    <NavLink to="/bookings">Bookings</NavLink>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <button onClick={context.logout}>Logout</button>
                  </li>
                </React.Fragment>
              )}
            </ul>

          </nav>
        </header>
      );
    }}
  </AuthContext.Consumer>
);

export default mainNavigation;
```

Answer (score 0):

`<h1><NavLink to={'...'}>Lux Lab Hair Salon</NavLink></h1>` or just a `<NavLink style={{ fontSize: '20px' }}>Lux Lab Salon</NavLink>`

Comment: It worked. I had to import BrowserRouter to help with the navigation path.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem is how to call for a component in a react navigation bar.
Here are the steps I followed to resolve the problem.

1. I imported BrowserRouter in App.js and used it to define the path of the homepage
   in App.js

   ```
    import {BrowserRouter, Route, Redirect, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
    import Homepage from './pages/Homepage';

    class App extends Component {
        render() {
            return (<BrowserRouter>
                <React.Fragment>

                    <Navigation/>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route path="/" component={Homepage}/>
                        <Route path="/nav1path" component={Page1Component}/>
                        <Route path="/nav2path" component={Page2Component}/>
                        {!this.state.token && <Redirect to="/" exact/>}
                    </Switch>

                </React.Fragment>
            </BrowserRouter>);
        }
    }

    export default App;
   ```
2. Then I used the suggestion above to circle my H1 tag with NavLink.

   <NavLink to={'/'}>
    Header title

Also don't forget to import other components before you call them inside Route.